# Confused on how to design my database for a checklist app

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

I have a checklist app that I am trying to design a database for.

A checklist is composed of a bunch of tabs (sections of the checklist) and each tab has a number of checklist_items. A checklist can be started and completed. When completed, a user can create a new checklist afterwards. I'm trying to design the database but what is confusing me is how I can design it so that I can query something like:

Across all checklists created, how many items on the "Household" tab were checked off?

I have an initial design:

[image]

When I create my first checklist, my tab table will look like:

```
tab_id, checklist_id, name
1,      1,            "Household"
2,      1,            "Outdoors"
3,      1,            "Work"
4,      1,            "School"
```

And my checklist_item tab will look like :

```
   checklist_item_id, checklist_id, tab_id, checked
   1,                 1,            1,      0
   2,                 1,            1,      0
   3,                 1,            1,      0
   4,                 1,            2,      0
   5,                 1,            2,      0
   6,                 1,            2,      0
   7,                 1,            3,      0
   8,                 1,            3,      0
   9,                 1,            3,      0
   10,                1,            4,      0
   11,                1,            4,      0
   12,                1,            4,      0
```

The checklist items only know about the tab_id, and when there are multiple checklists, it wont be as easy as saying `select from checklist_item where tab_id = 1` because there will be more tab entries for Household, so how could I figure out something like the query above? Also, is what I have so far bad design? Is there a better way of approaching this?

EDIT: It is worth mentioning I am new to database design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tables are fine.  You can still use your query `SELECT * FROM checklist_item WHERE tab_id = 1` since tab_id uniquely determines checklist_id (i.e. each tab belongs to a specific checklist), so there won't be any confusion between the Household entries of different checklists (each will have its own tab_id).

If you want to get the Household items across all checklists, join checklist_item with tab like so:

```
SELECT i.*
FROM checklist_item i
INNER JOIN tab t ON i.tab_id = t.tab_id
WHERE t.name = 'Household'
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused, with that join query I could get all the items that were checked on the Household tab across ALL checklists?

Comment: No, the query specifies checklist_id = 1.

Comment: But that query that I explained, is that possible with my model?  Get all the items that were checked on the Household tab across ALL checklists?

Answer (score 0):

Well I learned it with http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

I think you are missing the join in your query.

```
SELECT CI.checklist_item_id, CIchecked, T.checklist_ID, T.name, C.time_started, C.time_ended
FROM checklist_item CI 
LEFT JOIN tab T ON CI.tab_id = T.tab_id 
LEFT JOIN checklist C ON CI.checklist_id = C.checklist_id
WHERE tab_id = 1
```

Comment: So my design would allow me to do the query I questioned about above?

Comment: Yes. I didn't preform one join. The join on the tab to checklist.